# Questions about minimum detectable RF signal level

Tags: detection

I would like to estimate the ideal minimum detectable power levels for a few different tuners. I am wondering the best way to go about doing this just by using well-known engineering equations along with the manufacturer supplied data sheets.

The tuner will be scanning for new signals beginning at 100 MHz. I wish to use an IFBW of 10 MHz. Assumed detection threshold of 12 dB above noise floor to call it a ‘detection’. Input signals are assumed to be modulated analog signals.

For a tuner with 15 dB NF, 10 MHz BW and using the formula MDS = -174 + 10log(BW) + NF, I get a result of -89 dBm. Applying my detection threshold of 12 dB now means a 'detection' occurs at -89 + 12 = -77 dBm.

If a 20 kHz AM vs. a 20 kHz FM signals is injected into the tuner, (at different times)  how does my detection threshold change, if at all - assuming I'm still using a 10 MHz filter?

I have additional params such as dBc/Hz from the manufacturer. How can I get a more accurate estimate of the MDS without actually making measurements?

-reacher33

Answer (score 0):

The two parameters I can think of effecting minimum detectable signal will be noise figure (dominantly) and local oscillator phase noise. As you properly determined, your MDS is dependent on the noise figure since you dictated a threshold of 12 dB above the noise floor. As far as different modulations (AM, FM, digital modulations such a QAM, QPSK, BPSK, different coding schemes and multiplexing schemes etc), each will dictate a SNR criteria for minimum signal detection (typically based upon an minimum error rate or acquisition time etc).

Phase noise can also limit the achievable bit error rate (or even ability to receive) for a given modulation type, so that needs to be considered carefully in the interest of minimum detectable signals. If the phase noise is good enough to demodulate but poor enough to degrade the signal SNR, then when the phase noise combines with the noise floor under minimum detectable signal conditions, that level of detection will be raised due to the sum of those two independent noise sources.

As for other parameters there are many other concerns that the datasheet will inform  but none that would significantly effect MDS that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It sounds like I need to compute an equivalent noise figure based on the apparent noise floor and the local oscillator phase noise, also described here: https://www.rfcafe.com/references/articles/wj-tech-notes/effect-LO-phase-noise-receiver-sensitivity-v8-6.pdf

Comment: Yes - I didn’t read the detailed paper but know that the modulation details have a big effect on that— for example as I describe in other posts here the carrier recovery loop in a typical receiver that is tracking the low frequency variations of the carrier frequency, and therefore the phase of it as well, will act like a high pass filter to the phase noise contribution. I think you need to consider all that which is receiver specific when determining sensitivity. Although in most cases it will be noise figure alone: if the LO is limiting sensitivity then I would say the LO isn’t good enough.